# Basemap returns error when plotting for better qualities than low and crude

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I am using Basemap to draw a map as follows:

```
lat_0 = 49
lat_1 = 60.16
lon_1 = -109.8
lon_0 = -120.2

m1 = Basemap(projection='ortho', lon_0=lon_0, lat_0=lat_0, resolution=None)
map = Basemap(projection='ortho',lon_0=lon_0,lat_0=lat_0,resolution='f',\
    llcrnrx=0.,llcrnry=0.,urcrnrx=m1.urcrnrx/15.,urcrnry=m1.urcrnry/10.)
```

Now, if the resolution is set to `c` or `l`, it runs fine, if I increase the resolution to `i`, `h` or `f` - it throws the following Traceback exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\WindDataAnalyze.py", line 277, in <module>
    DrawFig()
  File ".\WindDataAnalyze.py", line 188, in DrawFig
    llcrnrx=0.,llcrnry=0.,urcrnrx=m1.urcrnrx/15.,urcrnry=m1.urcrnry/10.)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 1112, in __init__
    self._readboundarydata('gshhs',as_polygons=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-        packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 1456, in _readboundarydata
    if not poly.is_valid(): poly=poly.fix()
  File "_geoslib.pyx", line 242, in _geoslib.BaseGeometry.fix     (src/_geoslib.c:2279)
  File "_geoslib.pyx", line 346, in _geoslib.Polygon.__init__     (src/_geoslib.c:3609)
IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I think, it has to do with the projection `ortho`, since projection `lcc` works with full resolution.
I am clueless as what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!